# Are browsers optimized for different image aspect ratios?

Tags: image, performance, browser, gif, css-sprites

This question might have a very complex answer, but here goes:

I have created some image sprites using a naive stacking algorithm which produces images that are 89px wide by 2000px tall. This image will be used for about 50 sprites on a page. The sprite is in .GIF format, and I know almost nothing about how GIF encodes pixels, (I don't know if it's row/column-major, or some other packing algo).

The total number of pixels in the sprite image is 178,000.

I could alter my sprite generation algorithm to produce a sprite that is 445px wide by 400 tall (same number of pixels, just creating a grid of images instead of a single column).

**Does changing the configuration of the sprite produce better browser DOM load/render performance? (I'm  especially interested IE 8 and mobile browsers, like Safari on iOS)**

Answer (score 1):

As with all optimization questions ... it's hard to say without measuring it.

BUT ... based on the way GIF files are encoded I suspect that your current layout will perform 'better' than a more-even aspect ratio image.

Documentation on the GIF file format says "It is therefore likely that one scan line will end and another begin in the middle of a sub-block of image data".

Since the image data is LZW compressed, and since pixels from the same icon are more likely to be the same color (even if they are from opposite edges and one row down), it's likely that your current layout will compress better and therefore it's likely to perform better.

But I'm sure there are plenty of pathological cases where the converse is true, and equally confident that any performance gain from either layout is likely to be so small that there are undoubtedly better optimizations to go worry about.

Comment: Having implemented the grid layout and compared file sizes, there was virtually no difference in file size in this case ( < 1kB on a 208kB file). In Chrome, it does seem to have made a minor difference in perf, but that's on only a few runs, and who knows what other factors played in. IE 8 is notoriously hard to instrument, so I am not yet sure how to measure.